# Can SFMC send a triggered message when the NextKeyword times out?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, triggered-send, sms

In mobile studio, you can configure a NextMessage and set the timeframe. This means that the user has X amount of minutes to reply back before their reply will no longer carry the keyword to trigger the next message.

Is there a way to deploy a message when the nextmessage times out? Essentially, I'm trying to deploy a proactive message to let the user know their conversation has timed out, realtime. I don't want to use an automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can't think of an out-of-the-box solution. But let me suggest this if you are sending the SMS from a Journey:

Add an X minutes wait activity after your SMS activity + combine it with the solution provided by Eliot here:

[Capture SMS response on Journey Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296800/capture-sms-response-on-journey-builder)

**Step 6:** create a decision split with two paths. In the first path where the contact is not found in the data extension (did not reply), you can send another SMS. In the second path, do something else depending on your needs...

Comment: This was a great suggestion. I also found something helpful here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140835/journey-builder-decision-split-when-a-de-has-multiple-entries-for-a-subscriber


So I'm going to test it out, by generating a GUID for the initiaton of the conversation, and then use the DE that tracks teh replies to track inbound messages, like you suggested. I will follow up to let you know how it works.